# The contraction principle in quasi metric spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

I am researching contractive mappings and I need the article of I. A. Bakhtin "*The contraction principle in quasi metric spaces*"(1989) or at least part where explanation is given for introduction of quasi metric spaces (in contemporary literature they are called b-metric spaces)  as it is a pioneering work in the field but impossible to find.
Is there anyone who has read this paper or knows the answer to the question?

Comment: Send me your address email .
Im interests research in b-metric space